# Composition of analytic functions is analytic in a general setting, and are they continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Regarding the notion of analyticity discussed in this setting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533790/a-possible-equivalence-for-holomorphicity I wonder if this is truly the correct definition (even though it is from Dunford-Schwarz)

An easy check verifies that linear maps from all of $X$ to $Y$ are analytic, so that therefore there can be noncontinuous analytic functions in the sense linked above.

Is it true that compositions of analytic functions are analytic?

Comment: _Continuous_ linear maps are analytic. Aside, Dunford-Schwartz, with a "t".

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah my mistake on the spelling.  But any linear maps $L$ are analytic.  Take $z_1, ..., z_n$ and consider the associatedcoordinatization map I mentioned in my last post linked here.  Call that $T$. Take a linear functional $\phi$, and do the triple sandwich $\phi \circ L \circ T$.  This is linear from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$ hence analytic in the classical sense, which is what is required as per the definition given by Dunford and Schwartz. (They do not require continuity.  I did catch them forgetting it once elsewhere where it was needed, but they are pretty good.)

Comment: Ah, right, forgot that you precompose with a _linear_ map.

Comment: That settles the other question then, Fréchet-differentiability implies continuity.

Comment: @DanielFischer not if I allow for the Frechet derivative to be unbounded.  Btw how do you get those accents?

Comment: In my definition of Fréchet-derivative, it is a continuous linear map. But whatever. For the accents, I copy and paste.

Comment: @Jeff: If you're on a Mac, accents come from option+, just as in any word processor.